# How to control CSS pseudo elements :before and :after to disappear when text is removed using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**CSS**

```
    h2:before, h2:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -87px;
    top: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: #cdcdcb;
    }

   ------ text -------- <!-- looks something like this --->
```

Comment: I have used CSS but the pseudo elements are not consistent sizes using percents as it is in pixels

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? or provide a JFiddle. If I understand correctly, you don't need JS for this. Unless I miss something. It seems to simple to be a problem

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I thought at first. But making the height a percent will remove the pseudo elements if no text is in the html element, but it does not display consistent sizes throughout the rest of the page layout. Here is a jFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/n41f366e/

Comment: I was thinking it has something to do with the height property being a percent. When its it px it stays a consistent size. But the pseudo elements will stay if the text is removed

Comment: I think what you are seeing might be the margins...see what happens when you use a reset - http://jsfiddle.net/n41f366e/7/ However, it's not clear what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The position absolute is not necessary, specially when you are dealing with pseudoclasses. Delete these position properties and wrap your H2 content in a span tag that will be dynamic (it will be removed with the text). Taht way your H2 remains undeleted. Then attach your pseudoclasses to the span tags.

```
<!-- With the text in h2 tag -->
   <h2><span>This is h2 heading</span></h2>

<!-- Without text in h2 tag -->
<p>Start</p>
   <h2><!--<span>This is h2 heading</span>--></h2>
<p>End</p>

h2 span:before, h2 span:after {
   content: '---';    
   height: 7%;
   width: 75px;
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

This will give you the desired result without overloading with unnecessary JS

[**JFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n41f366e/8/)

Comment: `:before` and `:after` are pseudo-**elements** *not* pseudo-classes

Comment: yeah that's what I meant. I don't memorize terms too well. Seems like a waster of time unless I was in college and had to pass a test. :)